# how we can reach at RAM size by summing up the memory occupied by processes and free memory in linux?

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel

I want to know to how to calculate total RAM, how we can reach at RAM size by summing up the output of "cat proc/meminfo" command

Memtotal = MemFree+?...........

any one can help

Comment: Why would the want a process to compute the total memory available when this information is already exported by the OS ?   You have to use the output provided by `dmidecode` or `cat /proc/meminfo | grep -i Total`.

Answer (score 0):

You need a tool that takes shared memory into account to do this.

For example, [smem](http://www.selenic.com/smem/):

```
# smem -t
  PID User     Command                         Swap      USS      PSS      RSS
...
10593 root     /usr/lib/chromium-browser/c        0    22868    26439    49364 
11500 root     /usr/lib/chromium-browser/c        0    22612    26486    49732 
10474 browser  /usr/lib/chromium-browser/c        0    39232    43806    61560 
 7777 user     /usr/lib/thunderbird/thunde        0    89652    91118   102756 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  118 4                                       40364   594228   653873  1153092
```

`PSS` is the interesting column here because it takes shared memory into account (adding `RSS` together will result in shared mem segments being counted multiple times so numbers won't add up).

So userland processes take up 654Mb total here.

```
# smem -tw
Area                           Used      Cache   Noncache 
firmware/hardware                 0          0          0 
kernel image                      0          0          0 
kernel dynamic memory        345784     297092      48692 
userspace memory             654056     181076     472980 
free memory                   15828      15828          0 
----------------------------------------------------------
                            1015668     493996     521672
```

346Mb is used by the kernel and there's 16Mb free.
Overall about half of memory is used for cache (494Mb).

So 1Gb <sub>RAM total</sub> = 654Mb <sub>userland processes, broken up as above</sub> + 346Mb <sub>kernel mem</sub> + 16Mb <sub>free</sub>
(give or take a few Mb)

Comment: how can we do by proc/meminfo commands output details. which field is related to process

Comment: Actually a really good exercise if you want to learn this stuff is to rewrite smem. You'll learn everything about parsing /proc data, getting info about shared mem segments, computing PSS etc. It's all [here](http://selenic.com/repo/smem/file/c2cab19139d0/smem) and [there](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc)